# Raspberry Pi Static IP setup for wlan0 not working

Tags: networking, wifi, static-ip

I am trying to create a static ip for my wlan0 connection.  Here is my modified /etc/network/interfaces file

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 10.0.xx.xx
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.65.1
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

However, once I reboot I cannot connect to the network.  Is there something wrong with this file?

Comment: In the line `address 10.0.xx.xx`, there should not be those `x`'s.  Did you put those in just for on here or is that your actual file?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would provide the output of `ifconfig wlan0` and `iwconfig wlan0` as well. This way we may be able to see what's wrong. The output of `route` may help as well.

Comment: hey sorry guys.  The problem that there was a security issue in my network.  I had done everything correctly.  Once the security issue was resolved, everything worked correctly.  Thanks!